# Why does omitting the line app.use(express.static(__dirname, 'public')) stop my html pages from loading css files?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm learning to use NodeJS and Express and just used "express" to generate the scaffolding for a project. I don't understand the purpose of:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

My understanding of app.use() is that it loads functions as middleware, so `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))` must be loading a function, right? Is this function loading paths to some files that I'm declaring as static?

In my layout.jade file, I have this line in the head:

`link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')`

How does my app know to begin the href link with a '/public' (if that's what it's doing) when I set the `app.use(express.static)` line? Because when I get rid of the `app.use(express.static)` line, it gives a 404 to finding the css file, even when I change the href to '/public/stylesheets/style.css'.

And how does it know that I'm trying to access that static file at all? What if I had a file called 'root/stylesheets/style.css' as well as the 'root/public/stylesheets/style.css'?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Right, `app.use()` loads a function to be used as middleware. In this context, it **loads the result of** `express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))`.

The result of `express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))` is a **function** (in JavaScript, functions may return functions), a function that express understands as a middleware (i.e. it has the following signature: `function(request, response, next) {`

`express.static()` is a function that takes a path, and returns a middleware that serves all files in that path to `/`. (If you wanted to prefix it with `/public` or whatever, you'd write `app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))`, where the first `/public` is the *web path* and the second is the *filesystem path* of the files being served).

---

For better clarity, the following:

```
app.use('/a', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'b')));
```

would serve all files inside of the `b` directory, and have them accessible through `http://example.com/a/FILE`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. But how does `layout.jade` know where to find the `style.css`? Is it accessible through `http://example.com/stylesheets/style.css`?

Comment: Well, under the `/public` directory on your server, there's a `stylesheets` directory and inside of it there's a `style.css`. `express.static()` knows to resolve directories recursively.

Comment: What happens if I have two `style.css` files? Does it just return the first one it finds? 

So does `express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))` serve all `/` files (would this be all files, or just direct child files of `/`?) with the contents of `/public` and this is how `layout.jade` can access `/stylesheets/style.css`?

Comment: How would there be two `style.css` files in the same directory? Also, it would serve all of the files in the `public` directory, under the `/` web path.

Comment: I just realised that having two `style.css` files makes no sense.

Ohhhh, I think I got it. `express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))` allows the contents of `/public` to be accessed from `/` , which is how `layout.jade` finds the CSS when the app is run using node. 

Last question: what's the importance of using `express.static`? Wouldn't I also be able to use some sort of `app.use('/', function(req, res) {//get file from /public})`.

Thanks so much for the help by the way =)

Comment: @jazza_m8 You would. But then you'll have to handle: mime types, headers, directories, file reading. Since it's a super common usecase, a helper function was created for you :)